# Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid - Netbeans, MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, glassfish, java-ee-7

I'm following the tutorial of Netbeans site:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html

everything was working fine until this step: Implementing JSTL code STEP 4 where the list should be displayed I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused."
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException :
         Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused."
```

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

I suppose netbeans still tries to connect to the Derby DB. How can i change it to MySQL DB?
I am using Java EE7, MySQL, Netbeans, Glassfish 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.x and Java EE Version 5 or 6 
Then it works.

Comment: You need to follow all the directions in the NetBeans Tutorial you linked to above. It links to a tutorial on connecting to MySql (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) and the instructions specifically detail how to use an existing JDBC connection to create the JDBC resource used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace indicates that the MySQL DB is not running on port 1527

See https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

Comment: yes, definetly i finished first this tutorial, and everything was ok. i wrote the port for MySQL 3306

Comment: ah I see. so like you said in the question u need to figure out why nb is referencing what looks like a Derby conn string.

Comment: might be useful to name your OS so we can provide OS specific troubleshooting and health checking tips.

Comment: i found the solution: I tried it with Glassfish 3 and Java EE 5 then it just worked! I think there is a problem with Glassfish 4 and Java EE 7, it is probably because of the Jstl, but i am not so sure.

Comment: Fair play, well done!  You should accept your own answer so that future visitors can quickly see that it was what worked for you.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it Accepting and Voting for yourself is not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using a different approach. I changed the settings in the glassfish-web.xml file found in IFPWAFCAD/WebPages/WEB-INF folder. The following settings worked for me for this particular tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html:

---

Resource Reference name: **jdbc/IFPWAFCAD** 
JNDI Name: **jdbc/IFPWAFCAD**
Principal Name: **root**
Principal Password: **nbuser**

---

These settings will work for this particular tutorial - I used glassfish 4 - and Java EE 5. No need to install glassfish 3

Comment: but in glassfish 4, you can only use java ee 7, how did u change it?